# data mismatch when reading .bin file in gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, filesystems, fopen

I want to implement FOTA in stm32,
for that I am reading . bin file in gcc compiler and send data serially to uart.
but ther is mismatch between file read and actual file.  I compare data, then i found that fread function does not read proper data, then i print data of 200 byte and compare with online .bin to hex converter and stm32programmer. I found that the problem in fread function. but how come i dont know.below is the code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
uint8_t DATA_BUF[1024];
uint8_t APP_BIN[80000];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int comport;
  int bdrate   = 115200;       /* 115200 baud */
  char mode[]={'8','N','1',0}; /* *-bits, No parity, 1 stop bit */
  char bin_name[1024];
  int ex = 0;
  FILE *Fptr = NULL;

  do
  {
    if( argc <= 2 )
    {
      printf("Please feed the COM PORT number and the Application Image....!!!\n");
      printf("Example: .\\etx_ota_app.exe 8 ..\\..\\Application\\Debug\\Blinky.bin");
      ex = -1;
      break;
    }

//get the COM port Number
comport = atoi(argv[1]) -1;
strcpy(bin_name, argv[2]);
  // ex = sizeof(ETX_OTA_HEADER_);
  // printf("Opening COM%d...\n", ex );
printf("Opening COM%d...\n", comport+1 );

//if( RS232_OpenComport(comport, bdrate, mode, 0) )
//{
//  printf("Can not open comport\n");
 // ex = -1;
 // break;
//}

//send OTA Start command
  //ex = send_ota_start(comport);
//if( ex < 0 )
//{
//  printf("send_ota_start Err\n");
//  break;
//}

printf("Opening Binary file : %s\n", bin_name);

Fptr = fopen(bin_name,"rb");

if( Fptr == NULL )
{
  printf("Can not open %s\n", bin_name);
  ex = -1;
  break;
}

fseek(Fptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
uint32_t app_size = ftell(Fptr);
fseek(Fptr, 0L, SEEK_SET);

printf("File size = %d\n", app_size);

//Send OTA Header
//meta_info ota_info;
//ota_info.package_size = app_size;
//ota_info.package_crc  = 0;          //TODO: Add CRC

//ex = send_ota_header( comport, &ota_info );
//if( ex < 0 )
//{
 // printf("send_ota_header Err\n");
 // break;
//}

//read the full image
if(fread( APP_BIN, 1, app_size, Fptr ) != app_size )
{
  printf("App/FW read Error\n");
  ex = -1;
  break;
}
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 200; i++)
  {
      printf("%d  ",APP_BIN[i]);
  }
} while (false);

return(ex);
}
```

this one is original data when i used online .bin to hex converter

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x24, 0xA1, 0x0D, 0x10, 0x08, 0xED, 0x0A, 0x10, 0x08, 0xF3, 0x0A, 0x10, 0x08,
```

this is the data when fread function used

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x08, 0x24, 0x4D, 0x0C, 0x10, 0x08, 0x99, 0x09, 0x10, 0x08, 0x9F, 0x09, 0x10, 0x08,
```

I could not find out what is the problem.
if someone has already faced the same, plls guide me
thanking you.

Comment: No idea of your data (binary) file size, but you're read the entire size into a buffer that's 80000 bytes and no more... Perhaps you want to look into that discrepancy.. Also, serial comms can be a bit of a _black art_... "Smart devices" may need protection from an unknown byte stream (that could contain sequences they interpret as commands.)

Comment: "online Hex converter"... And your dump shows the first 200 bytes as decimal int values? That's not convenient...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help on how to ask a question. You're much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide a minimal _runnable_ program that allows people to reproduce your problem.  Posting  code that's messy and hard to read also decreases chances of an answer: bad indentation; useless constructs like `do { ... } while (false)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fseek` and `ftell` to find the size of a file is an anti-pattern. It's not necessary. Here is a more correct way to read a file's binary contents.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct bytes_s {
  uint8_t *buf;
  size_t size;
};

/* Read file contents as unsigned bytes. */
struct bytes_s read_bytes(FILE *f) {
  size_t buf_size = 1024, size = 0;
  uint8_t *buf = malloc(buf_size * sizeof *buf);
  for (;;) {
    size_t read_size = fread(buf + size, 1, buf_size - size, f);
    if (read_size == 0) break;
    size += read_size;
    buf_size *= 2;
    buf = realloc(buf, buf_size * sizeof *buf);
  }
  return (struct bytes_s) { .buf = realloc(buf, size), .size = size };
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2) exit(1);
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  if (!f) exit(2);
  struct bytes_s bytes = read_bytes(f);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes.size; ++i) {
    printf("%02x ", bytes.buf[i]);
    if ((i & 0xf) == 0xf) putchar('\n');
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Here's a run:

```
$ gcc rb.c -o rb
$ ./rb rb.c
23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65 20 3c 73 74 64 69 6f 2e 
68 3e 0a 23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65 20 3c 73 74 64 
6c 69 62 2e 68 3e 0a 23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65 20 
3c 73 74 64 69 6e 74 2e 68 3e 0a 0a 73 74 72 75 
63 74 20 62 79 74 65 73 5f 73 20 7b 0a 20 20 75 
[ rest elided ]
```

Now compare to Linux hex dump:

```
$ hexdump -C rb.c
00000000  23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65  20 3c 73 74 64 69 6f 2e  |#include <stdio.|
00000010  68 3e 0a 23 69 6e 63 6c  75 64 65 20 3c 73 74 64  |h>.#include <std|
00000020  6c 69 62 2e 68 3e 0a 23  69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65 20  |lib.h>.#include |
00000030  3c 73 74 64 69 6e 74 2e  68 3e 0a 0a 73 74 72 75  |<stdint.h>..stru|
00000040  63 74 20 62 79 74 65 73  5f 73 20 7b 0a 20 20 75  |ct bytes_s {.  u|
[ rest elided ]
```

Comment: It does seem wasteful to grow the buffer when the most recent read may have reached the end of the file (ie: read_size < buf_size - size), then go back to find there's zero more to actually read....

Comment: Same result with above code, i have screen shot of actual file and file  I am reading, but could not upload

Comment: please check my OP, I have edited the result.